# Asp.net <clientCache>

Tags: asp.net, caching

As part of static file caching in my application, I am using the clientCache> feature supported by IIS7.5. But I would like to invalidate the client side files while performing new deployments, to ensure that the stale files are removed.

cacheControlMaxAge seems to be absolute. I want to invalidate the files one time (during deployment) and then they should be cached. Is there any way recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Depends which files you are trying to invalidate. One solution could be to generate some sort of fingerprint and append it as a querystring to your files. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css?fp=hash_generated_from_file" >
```

When you change file you should recreate the hash and append it to the file. Mads Kristensen wrote an article [Cache busting in ASP.NET](http://madskristensen.net/post/Cache-busting-in-ASPNET.aspx) which would be the answer to your question. Instead of copying-pasting his article you might want to see how he does this.

Comment: Thanks. Fingerprinting is an option. Wanted to know if the Clientcache has support for any dependency. Idea is to have this done with config change.